# Work with method "getOrDefault()" of the Map

Tags: java, spring-mvc, generics

I want to get flashAttribute when from one page is redirected to another page and set it to model. And I try to use this code:

```
Map<String, ?> map = RequestContextUtils.getInputFlashMap(request);
if (map != null) {
    // this is redirect
    model.addAttribute("attr", map.getOrDefault("attr", false));
}
```

I have an error:

> The method getOrDefault(Object, capture#3-of ?) in the type
>   Map is not applicable for the arguments
>   (String,       boolean)

What can I do to solve this problem with getOrDefault("attr", false) method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make an unchecked cast of the map:

```
Map<String, Object> map =
    (Map<String, Object>) RequestContextUtils.getInputFlashMap(request);
```

The wildcard in the returned map type is rather wrong, it should have been `Map<String, Object>`.

In both cases, `get(K)` returns `Object`, but the wildcard forbids the methods with `?` type as an argument such as `V` in `put(K, V)`, which might pollute the type-correctness of the map contents.

The problem is that this also affects methods such as `getOrDefault(K, V)`, which do not actually modify the map.

Answer (score 0):

For wildcard values you can simply cast `map` for the call to `getOrDefault` to the value type you want:

```java
    model.addAttribute("attr", ((Map<String, Boolean>) map).getOrDefault("attr", false));
```